# How can I get multiple nth elements in a list?

Tags: list, haskell

I want to know how I can get multiple elements in a list in one function

for example if I wanted to get elements 1 2 3 and 4 from list `a`, I would have to type `a!!0 ++ a!!1 ++ a!!2 ++ a!!3`. This takes up a lot of space especially if the list name is more than one character. so I'm wondering if I can do something like `a!![0,1,2,3]` instead and get all of those elements in a much shorter way. Thank you.

Comment: `map (a!!) [0,1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with a mapping where you lookup all items for a list, so:

```
map (a !!) [0,1,2,3]
```

If you are however interested in the first four items, you can work with [**`take :: Int  -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take):

```
take 4 a
```

especially since looking up by an index (with `(!!)`) is not a common operation in Haskell: this is unsafe since it is not guaranteed that the index is in bounds. Most list processing is done with functions like `take`, `drop`, `sum`, `foldr`, etc.